# how to bind data bind cells using knockout

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a simple html table and I want to do some dynamic manipulations to the cells of this table. I am attaching metadata to cells using the data property and wants the object in this data property bound to cell rowspan, colspan, row, col etc. This data property will also bind to a property grid so that on changing the property in property grid the values are passed to cells. 
Can anyone help on how to data-bind the cells?

When a cell is selected I attach some metadata to data and manually set the cell attributes which is not a good approach so i want to data bind cells:-

```
 $(".selectable-cells").on('click', function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
                           var element= { row: r, column: c, rowspan: old_data.rowspan, columnspan: old_data.columnspan };

                            $(this).attr('rowspan', element.rowspan);
                            $(this).attr('colspan', element.columnspan);

                            $(this).data("element", element);

                        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have any code you can share? It sounds like you could utilize a combination of knockout's foreach and attr bindings, but without seeing what kind of data properties are being attached, it's hard to say.

Comment: @NickDeFazio added code in post..thanks!